# Getting values in hash map in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am not a java developer, and this is not my homework or something. I am just in need of getting the values of these parameters: end & begin. this is what I have:

```
rs = [{}, {end=2013/11/5, begin=2012/11/6}]
```

I am wonder if I could get values like this:

```
rs[1].end
rs[1].begin
```

the source is:

```
protected QueryParameters prepareForm(final ActionContext context) {
    final SearchErrorLogForm form = context.getForm();
    Map<String, Object> rs = form.getValues();
    System.out.println(rs);

    /*the output is: {pageParameters={}, period={end=2013/11/5, begin=2013/11/6}} */
}
```

sorry, the rs type is hashmap.

Comment: what's the data type of `rs`?

Comment: please go through java arrays http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: This does not look like Java for me,  Is it javascript?

Comment: JAVA arrays does not store values in this format. It's JavaScript,  JSON

Comment: Does not look like a java code to me. May be a javascript!

Comment: question updated. please recheck again. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a valid statement.

A proper way of assigning an array would be:

```
String dates[] = {"2013/11/5","2012/11/6"};
String start = dates[0];
String end = dates[1];
```

There is a excellent tutourial at [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Okay, that is a Map containing two Maps as it seems. The first map named "pageParameters" is empty. The second one is named period and contains two items. The key "end" maps to the value "2013/11/5". The key "begin" maps to the value "2013/11/6".

To access the objects in the map you could do like this:

```
final Map<String, String> period = (Map<String, String>) rs.get("period");
final String begin = period.get("begin");
final String end = period.get("end");
```

If you would like to change a value in the map period you will need to overwrite the already existing one:

```
period.put("end", "NEW_END");
rs.put("period", period);
```

For further information, Oracle has great [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) on Hashmaps.

Comment: for updating rs after processing begin and end date and creating new values from them, I used first periods.put(end, new_end); and periods.put(begin, new_begin); then updating rs.put(periods,periods) method but I think I did somewhere wrong cos it didnt work! could you help me to solve this too?

Comment: I have updated the answer with what I think you where asking for.

Comment: yes Its ok, thanks dude, I just missed "" on first parameters!

Answer (score 1):

you can do like following:

`rs[1][0]` for the first

`rs[1][rs[1].length-1]` for the last